# What are some checksum implementations that allow for incremental computation?

Tags: c++, checksum

In my program I have a set of sets that are stored in a proprietary hash table. Like all hash tables, I need two functions for each element. First, I need the hash value to use for insertion. Second, I need a compare function when there's conflicts. It occurs to me that a checksum function would be perfect for this. I could use the value in both functions. There's no shortage of checksum functions but I would like to know if there's any commonly available ones that I wouldn't need to bring in a library for (my company is a PIA when it comes to that).A system library would be ok.

But I have an additional, more complicated requirement. I need for the checksum to be incrementally calculable. That is, if a set contains A B C D E F and I subtract D from the set, it should be able to return a new checksum value without iterating over all the elements in the set again. The reason for this is to prevent non-linearity in my code. Ideally, I'd like for the checksum to be order independent but I can sort them first if needed. Does such an algorithm exist?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash

Comment: You can just keep a separate uint32_t counter -- initialize it to zero, and then whenever you add an item to the set, calculate the item's checksum and add it to your counter; and whenever you remove an item from the set, calculate the item's checksum and subtract it from your counter.  (Caching each item's checksum so that you don't have to calculate it more than once is optional)

Answer (score 1):

Simply store a dictionary of items in your set, and their corresponding hash value. The hash value of the set is the hash value of the concatenated, **sorted** hashes of the items. In Python:

```py
 hashes = '''dictionary of hashes in string representation'''
 # e.g.
 hashes = { item: hashlib.sha384(item) for item in items }

 sorted_hashes = sorted(hashes.values())
 concatenated_hashes = ''.join(sorted_hashes)
 hash_of_the_set = hashlib.sha384(concatenated_hashes)
```

As hash function I would use sha384, but you might want to try Keccak-384.

---

Because there are (of course) no cryptographic hash functions with a lengths of only 32-bit, you have to use a checksum instead, like Adler-32 or CRC32. The idea remains the same. Best use Adler32 on the items and crc32 on the concatenated hashes:

```
 hashes = { item: zlib.adler32(item) for item in items }

 sorted_hashes = sorted(hashes.values())
 concatenated_hashes = ''.join(sorted_hashes)
 hash_of_the_set = zlib.crc32(concatenated_hashes)
```

In C++ you can use [Adler-32](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1Adler32.html) and [CRC-32](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/classBotan_1_1CRC32.html) of [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/).

Comment: I should have mentioned, the hash key needs to be 32-bits. How would you handle the incremental nature of the computation as well?

Answer (score 1):

A CRC is a set of bits that are calculated from an input.

If your input is the same size (or less) as the CRC (in your case - 32 bits), you can find the input that created this CRC - in effect reversing it.

If your input is larger than 32 bits, but you know all the input except for 32 bits, you can still reverse the CRC to find the missing bits.

If, however, the unknown part of the input is larger than 32 bits, you can't find it as there is more than one solution.

Why am I telling you this? Imagine you have the CRC of the set

```
{A,B,C}
```

Say you know what `B` is, and you can now calculate easily the CRC of the set

```
{A,C}
```

(by "easily" I mean - without going over the entire `A` and `C` inputs - like you wanted)

Now you have 64 bits describing `A` and `C`! And since we didn't have to go over the entirety of `A` and `C` to do it - it means we can do it even if we're missing information about `A` and `C`.

So it looks like IF such a method exists, we can magically fix more than 32 unknown bits from an input if we have the CRC of it.

This obviously is wrong. Does that mean there's no way to do what you want? Of course not. But it does give us constraints on how it can be done:

**Option 1:** we don't gain more information from `CRC({A,C})` that we didn't have in `CRC({A,B,C})`. That means that the (relative) effect of `A` and `C` on the CRC doesn't change with the removal of `B`. Basically - it means that when calculating the CRC we use some "order not important" function when adding new elements:

we can use, for example, `CRC({A,B,C}) = CRC(A) ^ CRC(B) ^ CRC(C)` (not very good, as if A appears twice it's the same CRC as if it never appeared at all), or `CRC({A,B,C}) = CRC(A) + CRC(B) + CRC(C)` or `CRC({A,B,C}) = CRC(A) * CRC(B) * CRC(C)` (make sure `CRC(X)` is odd, so it's actually just 31 bits of CRC) or `CRC({A,B,C}) = g^CRC(A) * g^CRC(B) * g^CRC(C)` (where `^` is power - useful if you want cryptographically secure) etc.

**Option 2:** we do need all of `A` and `C` to calculate `CRC({A,C})`, but we have a data structure that makes it less than linear in time to do so if we already calculated `CRC({A,B,C})`.

This is useful if you want specifically CRC32, and don't mind remembering more information in addition to the CRC after the calculation (the CRC is still 32 bit, but you remember a data structure that's O(len(A,B,C)) that you will later use to calculate CRC{A,C} more efficiently)

How will that work? Many CRCs are just the application of a polynomial on the input.

Basically, if you divide the input into `n` chunks of 32 bit each - `X_1...X_n` - there is a matrix `M` such that

```
CRC(X_1...X_n) = M^n * X_1 + ... + M^1 * X_n
```

(where `^` here is power)

How does that help? This sum can be calculated in a tree-like fashion:

```
CRC(X_1...X_n) = M^(n/2) * CRC(X_1...X_n/2) + CRC(X_(n/2+1)...X_n)
```

So you begin with all the `X_i` on the leaves of the tree, start by calculating the CRC of each consecutive pair, then combine them in pairs until you get the combined CRC of all your input.

If you remember all the partial CRCs on the nodes, you can then easily remove (or add) an item anywhere in the list by doing just `O(log(n))` calculations!

---

So there - as far as I can tell, those are your two options. I hope this wasn't too much of a mess :)

I'd personally go with option 1, as it's just simpler... but the resulting CRC isn't standard, and is less... good. Less "CRC"-like.

Cheers!

Comment: Interesting thought. How does one calculate CRC(A)? Can you create a 32-bit number from a 32-bit number? I'd been doing option (1) until now but it has the disadvantage that most of the pointer values aren't random numbers but spread within a small range so (X+128) and (X-128) in one set has the same hash code as (X-16) and (X+16) if that makes sense.

Comment: @balor123 It makes sense if you use `^` as your operation in (1) - as xoring similar values cancels out most of the bits. If you use `+` or `*` as your operation - it shouldn't be a problem (but you will have other problems). In (2) I'm referring to any linear CRC (that uses a linear polynomial) - look at the wikipedia page for CRC. Option (2) is tricky to implement unless you're very familiar with linear algebra.

Comment: @balor123 Also - I just noticed that I used `CRC` as a general name for "checksum function" - sorry about the confusion :) So when I wrote `CRC(a)` I wasn't referring to anything specific but rather "whatever checksum function you want"